# asp.net: Inheriting from controls that use embedded resources and me.GetType()

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having some trouble trying to inherit a control that uses an embedded resource.
the trouble is - this control uses me.GetType() instead of GetType(ControlName).
now when I try to use the derived control, it looks for the resources in the derived control's assembly, instead of the base control assembly, and obviously - doesn't find them.

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the call is in the base control's definition, there isn't much you can do if you can't override the method where its called; you could duplicate the resource file if possible, or try to override that method where the resource is being called.  It's hard when you don't have control over the base class.

It's also hard to advise when I don't know what the code looks like; if you could post the signature of the part of the class in question and refer to this in your question, that would help.

HTH.

Comment: This points out the reason why control developers should not use `Me.GetType` when referencing resources. Before I read this post, I did not understand why (I have seen other posts where it is recommended to use `GetType(ControlName)` instead, but no explanation why).

Comment: Even better, its best to create an overridable method to return the explicit type instead.  This way, you can override the method and return whatever type you like...